# Prove $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if it satisfies the following condition

Tags: probability, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Let $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P}{(\Omega)}$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra and satisfies $A_n \in \mathcal{F}, A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for all $n \implies \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n \in \mathcal{F}$.

Proof given:

[image]

I don't get the logic of the 'if' part. To prove that F is a sigma algebra shouldn't we refer back to the definition and prove that it satisfies?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mathcal{F}$ is already  an **algebra**, we only need to show that if  $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{F}$ , then
$$\bigcup^\infty_{n=1} B_n \in \mathcal{F},$$
that is, we need to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable unions.

So, if  $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{F}$, define
$$A_n = \bigcup^n_{k=1} B_k.$$
Notice that $A_n \in \mathcal{F}$, because $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra and $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$.

Hence, by the 'only if' hipothesys, we know that 
$$\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}A_n = \bigcup^\infty_{n=1} \bigcup^n_{k=1} B_k = \bigcup^\infty_{k=1} B_k \in \mathcal{F} $$
showing that $\mathcal{F}$ is indeed  a $\sigma$-algebra.